# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Role"

Tags: mongoose

I am trying to join two collections and being able to get the combined data and found this error 
   ErrorMongoose error: Schema hasn't been registered for model. name: "MissingSchemaError".

RoleSchema.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var RoleSchema = new Schema({
    role_name: {type: String, required: true},
    create_time: Date,
    updated: Date
});

RoleSchema
    .virtual('url')
    .get(function () {
        return '/role/' + this._id;
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Role', RoleSchema, 'Role');
```

user_role.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var UserRoleSchema = new Schema({
    user_id: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
    role_id: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Role'},
    create_time: Date,
    updated: Date
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User_Role', UserRoleSchema, 'User_Role');
```

app.js:

```
mongoose.connect(mongoDB,options);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
```

userController.js:

```
UserRole.findOne({user_id: user._id}).populate('role_id').exec(function (error, doc) {
    //do something...
});
```

I have tried to fix it, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the type is wrong. It is not `Schema.ObjectId`, it is `Schema.Types.ObjectId`.

Also, `mongoose.model('User_Role', UserRoleSchema)` should be enough.